# PHP Ajax with a form

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form that let user to choose where them come from..

I have list out the country list by select box..

and i success to do it onchange and use ajax to read out all the state list..

actually i have two php file.. one is the main one that contain all the code include the form.. another one is generate state list.. my ajax code and form are in the main php

this is the one that generate state list...

```
    $cID = $_GET["country"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM States WHERE CountryID=$cID";
$result = $db->get_results($sql);
if (isset($result)) {                                 

            foreach ( $result as $states ) {
                ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkState[]" value="<?=$states->StateID?>" />&nbsp;<?=$states->StateName?><br />
                <?php
            }

}
```

this is part of my code that read out..

but my problem is...

where i submit the form..

i only get the variable of country.. i cannot take the data of state that use ajax to generate out...

sample of my form

```
<form action="" name="place">
<select name="cboCountry" class="drop" onchange="showState(this.value)">
//some php code the list out the country

</select>

<div id="txtHint">

            </div> 

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and here my ajax code

```
<script>
function showState(str)
{ 
alert('xxx');
var xmlhttp;
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","state_list.php?country="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

so when i submit the from with a save button... i only get the date of country and state are missing.. any body can help me? or having any way to do what i want?

Comment: Your AJAX codes are quite bulky, why don't you use jQuery ?

Comment: Do you see the state checkboxes when you fill in the form?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor can jquery do it?  sorry >.<.. im not much know about it.. and ajax too actually

Comment: @Barmar yes i have.. before i do it in ajax i use javascrpt to onchange it can be done... but i dun want it to refresh the whole page.. so i choose ajax

Comment: your're using a `checkbox` in selecting states? so the user can select many states at the same time?

Comment: @Þaw.. ya.. user can select many state on a same time..

Comment: but the checkboxes are in a `<select>` ?

Comment: @Þaw opps! sorry.. i typing error at here... cz i not copy from my code one...

Comment: so can you pls update your code?

Comment: is checkbox checked?, it will be submited only when it is checked

Comment: @Þaw ... done update//

Comment: @senk.. sure have checked...

Comment: I use this JS code all the time - nothing wrong with it and its much less bulky than JQuery if all you need is ajax...

Comment: @RobertSeddon-Smith i also no idea why that i cant to get the variable when submit the form..

Comment: If the AJAX is successfully adding the checkboxes to the form, I don't see why they wouldn't get included when you submit the form.

Comment: Are you getting output from the ajax in your html? If yes then check the <form> open and close . That might create problem.

Comment: There is another error in your ajax php script there is tr and td and you are displaying it in div that is not a valid html after ajax.